# Grey screen when pressing P in BGE

Tags: game-engine

Eveything was working fine while I was in the BGE until for a reason I don't know, the scene doesn't render. Or to be more exact the 1st layer doesn't render.

I tried to copy all layer 1 objects to layer 2 and then when I pressed P, layer 2 stopped rendering as well.

What do I do wrong? I've seen people talking about clipping etc. but I didn't mess with any settings.

Here's the [blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45902) so you can recreate the above.

Comment: you disabled rendering for those object, look in the outliner...

Comment: Well, thank you! I must have pressed a shortcut that I am not aware of when I had picked them all. I didn't get suspicious at all to check there. Make it into an answer and I'll mark it. One other might stumble on the same problem.

Comment: @Lev You might have pressed W > Restrict Render unselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @m.ardito correctly noticed I had disabled rendering for the objects, which is clearly visible in the outliner.